# How come Android replaces new-line characters with spaces for both TextView and notification?

Tags: android, textview, android-notifications

### Background

I have an input string that I need to show in limited number of lines (1 in this case, but might change), and on notification.
The text might have new-line charcaters ("\n"), so if it's limited, it shouldn't show the lines below.

### The problem

Suppose you have some string you want to show on TextView, but this string has some new lines in it.

Example:

```
textView.text = "Hello\n\nWorld"
```

If you set `android:maxLines="1"` and/or `android:singleLine="true"`, indeed it puts everything in a single line, but it will just replace the new lines with spaces :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2V4v.png]

Not only that, but trying to set the text in the notification, I see the exact same behavior, yet there it's not supposed to be restricted by number of lines. There I also see "Hello  World"...

Here's a snippet of it:

```
        val builder = ...
        builder.setSmallIcon(...)
        builder.color = ...
        builder.setContentTitle(...)
                .setTicker(...).setContentText(theProblematicText)
```

### What I've tried

I tried various attributes for TextView, but I couldn't find one that will fix it.

I know I could, if I wanted to, just parse the input text and cut it when I reach the first "\n", but this is not a good solution because it handles just a single line limitation, and also doesn't solve the issue for notifications.

### The questions

1. Why does Android replace those characters with simple spaces?
2. How can I avoid it for both TextView and Notification?
3. How can I make the TextView show only the first X lines of the input text? Do I really have to parse it?

Comment: try using html tag handler https://abhiandroid.com/ui/html

Comment: But it's not HTML tags. It's just "\n" ...

Comment: you can use <br> for new line

Comment: @VishalThakkar The input has "\n" .